# Strangeness with bash not operator

Tags: bash, file, exists

I'm trying to determine if a file or directory doesn't exist. I tried the following commands to see if a file does exist and they work correctly:

```
if [ -a 'settings.py' ]; then echo 'exists'; fi
exists #output
if [ -a 'foo' ]; then echo 'exists'; fi #outputs nothing
```

But when I try this:

```
if [ ! -a 'settings.py' ]; then echo 'does not exist'; fi
does not exist #shouldn't be output since the file does exist
if [ ! -a 'foo' ]; then echo 'does not exist'; fi
does not exist
```

'does not exist' is output no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `-e` in place of `-a`

This page on the [Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) says:

`-a` is identical in effect to `-e`. But it has been deprecated, and its use is discouraged.

Comment: Yeah.  Further explanation: `-a` is interpreted as "and" rather than "existence test" when it's not the first thing after `[`.  "Not and" is meaningless, you say?  Ayup.  This is one of the many reasons why you should never use `-a`/`-o` in their "and"/"or" meanings, either; use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` / `[ ... ] || [ ... ]` instead.  Annoyingly verbose, you say?  Ayup.  Shell sucks, film at eleven.

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems with the `[` command before. I prefer the `[[` variant since it's much more powerful and, in my experience, less prone to "gotchas" like this.

If you use the `[[` command, your test commands work fine:

```
pax> touch qq
pax> if [[ -a qq ]] ; then echo exists ; fi
exists
pax> if [[ ! -a qq ]] ; then echo not exists ; fi
pax> rm qq
pax> if [[ ! -a qq ]] ; then echo not exists ; fi
not exists
```

Comment: I couldn't disagree more -- `[` is portable, if you know all its quirks; `[[` cannot be relied upon to exist.

Comment: @Zack, the question is tagged `bash`. I'm aware that other shells may not provide it. And I'm sure you could disagree more - you just have to try harder :-)

Comment: Also, with `[[` you can use `&&` and `||` without having to break up the bracketed expressions. `[[ foo && bar || baz ]]` instead of `[ foo ] && [ bar ] || [ baz ]`

Comment: I don't believe in writing bash-specific shell scripts; if you need something that portable shell doesn't have it's time to break out a real scripting language...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `test`

```
test -e "$file" && echo "exists"
```